# How to make a list to split into each element and make a sublist

Tags: python

If I have this list,

```
list01 = ['GAGGT','TCCGT','ABECF']
```

I want to make each element in the list to split, but still remain in the same box of list. 
Like this:

```
listalt = [['G','A','G','G','T'],['T','C','C','G','T'],['A','B','E','C','F']]
```

Comment: `listalt = [list(i) for i in list01]`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh that's the correct answer - make it an answer :)

Comment: By the way if you want to type-cast string to `list` just for the sake of iteration, then you'll be amazed to know that the strings are also iterable (i.e. you can iterate them character by character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
final_list=[]
for item in list01:
    final_list.append(list(item))

print(final_list)
```

which is same as :

```
print([list(item) for item in list01])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
listalt = [list(i) for i in list01]
```

This is a [list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk), and uses the fact that [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list) can take an iterable (like a string) and turn it into a `list`